# Curriculum Learning: Academy updates twice in first lesson

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm training a brain with curriculum learning, and I experience that the academy updates the reset parameters twice in the first lesson, see image. 
Link to image [here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1gy1qZgR79oheSe93M3body1MaUlEl2vn/view?usp=sharing)

I invoke the resetting of the academy through a check if the reset parameters has changed, as I won't to avoid using max steps.

```
public override void InitializeAcademy()
  {
    environments = GameObject.FindGameObjectsWithTag("Ground");
    extendX = (environments[0].transform.localScale.x) / 2;// The first element in the environments array are used, because all environments are identical, and it therefore doesn't matter.
    extendZ = (environments[0].transform.localScale.z) / 2;

    previousMovingSensors = (int)resetParameters["NumberOfMovingSensors"];
    previousSensors = (int)resetParameters["NumberOfSensors"];
    previousClouds = (int)resetParameters["NumberOfSensorClouds"];
    previousRadius = (float)resetParameters["Radius"];

    // Disabling all obstacle at initialisation
    GameObject[] obstacles = GameObject.FindGameObjectsWithTag("Obstacle");
    for (var i = 0; i < obstacles.Length;i++)
    {
      obstacles[i].GetComponent<MeshRenderer>().enabled = false;
      obstacles[i].GetComponent<BoxCollider>().enabled = false;
    }

    // Defining the incrementer to be used for setting sensors.
    incrementer = obstacles.Length / environments.Length;
  }

  public override void AcademyReset()
  {
    lB = 0;
    uB = incrementer;

    foreach (GameObject environment in environments)
    {
      addMovingSensors(extendX,extendZ,environment.transform.position,environment.transform);
      addSensorClouds(extendX,extendZ,environment.transform.position,environment.transform);
      enableWalls(lB,uB);
      lB += incrementer;
      uB += incrementer;
    }

    // Status report
    // Debug.Log("Number of:");
    // Debug.Log("- moving sensors: " + GameObject.FindGameObjectsWithTag("Pedestrian").Length);
    // Debug.Log("- sensors in the clouds: " + GameObject.FindGameObjectsWithTag("Sensor").Length);
    // Debug.Log("- obstacles: " + processedObstacles.Count);
  }

  public void Update()
  {
    // Check if there has been any updates in the resetParameters.

    if ((previousMovingSensors != (int)resetParameters["NumberOfMovingSensors"]) ||
     (previousSensors != (int)resetParameters["NumberOfSensors"]) ||
      (previousClouds != (int)resetParameters["NumberOfSensorClouds"]) ||
       (previousRadius != (float)resetParameters["Radius"]))
    {
      Debug.Log("Test");
      // If changes has occured, reset the environment with the new resetParameters.
      // string[] objectsOfInterest = {"Sensor","Pedestrian"};
      //
      // foreach (string objectOfInterst in objectsOfInterest)
      // {
      //   GameObject[] objectsToDestroy = GameObject.FindGameObjectsWithTag(objectOfInterst);
      //   foreach(GameObject removeObject in objectsToDestroy)
      //   {
      //     Destroy(removeObject);
      //   }
      // }

      Done();

      previousMovingSensors = (int)resetParameters["NumberOfMovingSensors"];
      previousSensors = (int)resetParameters["NumberOfSensors"];
      previousClouds = (int)resetParameters["NumberOfSensorClouds"];
      previousRadius = (float)resetParameters["Radius"];
    }
  }
```

Does anyone have any idea why the academy updates twice in the first lesson?

Answer (score 0):

The answer is to not implement an update method..
I thought that it was necessary to either specify a max step number, or call "Done()" to reset the environment, but that is not the case. Resetting occurs as soon as the metric of choice reaches the specified value. Only set "max step" or call "Done()" if you need the environment to reset before the metric of choice reaches the specified value.
Which is also mentioned the documentations [here](https://github.com/Unity-Technologies/ml-agents/blob/master/docs/Learning-Environment-Design-Academy.md).